# COUNTIF formula if there's a timestamp (date and time)? As well as how to count number of entry per hour? [I forgot how do I do it before]

Tags: google-sheets, count, counter

I forgot how I used to do this formula as it was like 6-7 years ago **Geez**

So, I am aiming to get the number of entries with Timestamp (Date and time). Currently, I'm using TODAY (instead of NOW) as the based to count as I'm getting an error if I do COUNTIF with a time on it. I want to know what formula will work. Also, I want to know the formula on how will I get the count of entry per hour. I used to put the display time at Row 1, then specific hours on Row 2 (I hid this part usually) - and per date as well - see [Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11-grdJjXiENEvdGSobVDuGl8H1SmW5GlaermFKODxNk/edit?usp=sharing).

I am aiming to get the number of entries with Timestamp (Date and time). Currently, I'm using TODAY (instead of NOW) as the based to count as I'm getting an error if I do COUNTIF with a time on it. I want to know what formula will work. Also, I want to know the formula on how will I get the count of entry per hour. I used to put the display time at Row 1, then specific hours on Row 2 (I hid this part usually) - and per date as well - see [Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11-grdJjXiENEvdGSobVDuGl8H1SmW5GlaermFKODxNk/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's understand some basic formulas:

`YEAR("2023-04-05 22:15:28")=2023`
`MONTH("2023-04-05 22:15:28")=4`
`DAY("2023-04-05 22:15:28")=5`
`HOUR("2023-04-05 22:15:28")=22`

If you are able to add a temporary column which contains `YEAR/MONTH/DAY-HOUR` as text, then `COUNTIF` on this temporary column will be easier.

[image]

The formula in example is:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B, "=2023/4/5-22")
```